# Incorrect version of Pywin32 causing Scrapy error?

Tags: python, scrapy, pywin32

I am running Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista. I am trying to run Scrapy with the command:

```
scrapy startproject myproject
```

However this kicks out quite a big Traceback error log in Command Shell. Having done some further reading though, I believe it is only the last few lines in the log that are causing the error:

```
raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\
\cryptography\\_Cryptography_cffi_444d7397xa22f8491.pyd': DLL load failed: %1 is
 not a valid Win32 application.
```

A Google search for:

```
DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Reveals that this may be caused by Pywin32 not being installed. I have however installed the following Pywin .exe file:

```
pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7
```

In my Site Packages folder I have the following packages installed:

```
pythonwin
pywin32_system32
```

Is the above .exe the correct one to install and are the above two installed packages the correct ones I need for running Scrapy? Do I need a 64 bit version of Pywin?

If they are, can anyone thing what else might be causing this error? It is incredibly frustrating to be this close to having Scrapy working and falling at the final hurdle. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by installing OpenSSL 64 bit, instead of 32 bit. A bit of a schoolboy error, but I'm pretty pleased I managed to work out the root cause!